# Description for google play game services Match

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm implementing a game with turn based multiplayer with google play game services:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

My game has some different variations and in order to help users choose easily from the default UI, I would want to add a name for each match.

If it was possible, a player with for example 2 current matches would be able to identify each one easily without opening it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this information into your Turn data.  Like this...

```
// This is the byte array we will write out to the TBMP API.
public byte[] persist() {
    JSONObject retVal = new JSONObject();

    try {
        retVal.put("data", data);
```

...

You could then write a custom function to retrieve the match data and you would have to put that information into a custom inbox dialog.  I have not done this currently...

Comment: Thanks pvella, but the idea is to use the default UI. I'm afraid that for now is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is part of the standard product.  Look at the sample from google skeletonTBMP.java and also the skeletonTurn.java (I think it is called).  This is where you pass data between turns.  It would be fairly easy to populate this into the "data" object which gets updated at each turn, and then display this value on the screen as text.  Link here...
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/SkeletonTbmp/src/main/java/com/google/example/tbmpskeleton